# 400 bad request error when connecting to html with flask-socketio on gcp

Tags: python, flask, google-app-engine

here's the error sample

GET https://eco-crow-403708.de.r.appspot.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Ol3IX-n 400 (Bad Request)

This error appears every second on the console

It works fine locally, but I got an error when I uploaded it to gcp

my server.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from google.cloud import storage
import mysql.connector
from datetime import datetime
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="\*")

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket_name = "-"
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)

connection_name = "-"
conn = mysql.connector.connect(
unix_socket=f'/cloudsql/{connection_name}',
user='root',
password='-',
database='-',
)

cursor = conn.cursor()

@app.route('/', methods=\['POST', 'GET'\])
def index():
if request.method == 'POST':
try:
data = request.get_json()
if data and 'num_head' in data:
num_head = data\['num_head'\]
num_helmet = data\['num_helmet'\]
timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

            return jsonify(data), 200
        else:
            return jsonify({"message": "error"}), 400
    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({"message": "error"}), 400

return render_template('index.html', detection_data=detection_data)

@app.route('/update_notification', methods=\['POST'\])
def update_notification():
message = 'post.'
print('Sending notification: ' + message)
socketio.emit('notification', {'message': message})
return jsonify({"message": "Notification received."}), 200

if __name__ == '__main__':
socketio.run(app)
```

I tried changing the CORS settings and setting the port to fit, but all failed

Comment: Is this GAE Standard?